# The last array item is repeating for the last for loop due to which I am getting a concatenated string for my last loop

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the c++ code. I am getting the OUTPUT for the code as :

Enter the number of Adult : 2 
Enter the number of Child : 3 
Name atleast one of the Adult and a Child 
Adult name : a 
Adult name : b 
Child name : x
Child name : y
Child name : z
Number of Adult Customers : 2
Number of Child Customers : 3
Name of Adult 1 : a
Name of Adult 2 : b
Name of Child 1 : xz
Name of Child 2 : yz
Name of Child 3 : zz

Here the 2nd for loop is getting a concatenated output with each array item concatenating with the last array item. I tried changing the code from two typenames to only one typename but then there I faced some different output. I have given my code below. Does anyone know what is the exact issue with it? I just know the problem is with the array but I don't know the exact solution for it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename A, typename C>
class Booking
{
    private:
        A adult;
        C child;
      
    public:
        void setData(A x, C y)
        {
            adult = x;
            child = y;
        }
        A getAdultData()
        {
            return adult;
        }
        C getChildData()
        {
            return child;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int a1,c1;
    int i,j;
    
    string a[10];
    string c[10];

    Booking <int, int> obj1;
    Booking <string, string> obj2;

    cout<< "Enter the number of Adult : ";
    cin>>a1;
    cout<< "Enter the number of Child : ";
    cin>>c1;
    obj1.setData(a1,c1);
      cout<<"Name atleast one of the Adult and a Child"<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<=a1-1;i++)
    {
        cout<< "Adult name : ";
        cin>>a[i];
        obj2.setData(a[i],c[j]);
    }

    for(j=0;j<=c1-1;j++)
    {
    cout<< "Child name : ";
    cin>>c[j];
    obj2.setData(a[i],c[j]);
    }
    cout<<"Number of Adult Customers : "<<obj1.getAdultData()<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of Child Customers : "<<obj1.getChildData()<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<=a1-1;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Name of Adult "<<i+1<<" : "<<a[i]<<obj2.getAdultData()<<endl;
    }
    for(j=0;j<=c1-1;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Name of Child "<<j+1<<" : "<<c[j]<<obj2.getChildData()<<endl;
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are printing `... <<c[j]<<obj2.getChildData()<<endl;` when you probably only want `getChildData()` not `c[j]`. It isnt clear why you need `c` and `a` in the first place (at least they need not be arrays)

Comment: Which is the purpose of `obj2` (whereas you have `a` and `c`).

Comment: you only have a single `Booking<string,string>` but it seems you want `N` ? It isnt clear what the code is supposed to do in details. Frankly it looks like you went a little too fast. I would suggest to use a simple `std::pair<int,int>` and `std::pair<std::string,std::string>` for now if you really need just a pair of values of different types

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually without obj2 I was not able to call the setData method for `Booking <string, string>` as obj1 was conflicting with the `Booking <int, int>` when I use obj1 to call `Booking <string, string>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But for printing the value at a particular index I should use c[j]. Actually, I want multiple inputs from the user as a string due to which instead of declaring them as variable I declared them as array so that I am able to print all the input strings in the last once the user has stopped putting input.

Comment: Which is the purpose of `Booking`? `obj1` duplicates data of  `a1`, `c1` . `obj2` stores finally `a[a1]` (so empty or out of bound access), `c[c1 - 1]`...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry Sir for not being able to keep my code's objective in front of you. Basically I want the details of the customers in which one will be adult and other will be child. I first ask them about the number of adults and childs for which the code runs properly. But when I ask them about their name, I am facing some issues with it. Like, suppose if a user enters Number of Adults as 2 and Child as 3, so he must get 2 inputs to put the adults' name and 3 inputs to put the children's name. My code is running smoothly till here........continued

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But when it comes to printing, the last element array is getting concatenated with the 2nd for loop's output. I guess as you asked you only have a single `Booking<string, string>` but it seems you want N? I need N  `Booking<string, string>` so that the issue would be solved for it. Could you please tell me the syntax for it? It will be helpful

Comment: @Jarod42 Booking is class which has two typenames as Adult and Child.Basically I want the details of the customers in which one will be adult and other will be child. I first ask them about the number of adults and children for which the code runs properly. But when I ask them about their name, I am facing some issues with it. Like, suppose if a user enters Number of Adults as 2 and Child as 3, so he must get 2 inputs to put the adults' name and 3 inputs to put the children's name. Yes, `obj1` duplicated `a1` and `c1`. But I didn't get the `obj2` part you explained.

Comment: [Rubber_duck_debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): You currently have `obj2`, which is its purpose? what should it contains if you have 2 Adults and 3 Children. Maybe give more explicit name might help too. `obj1` might be renamed something like `count`/`number_of`, and `number_of.getAdultData()` returns the number of adults. Maybe `obj2` should be `Booking<std::vector<string>, std::vector<string>> names;`...

Comment: there is nothing being concatenated on the array elements. What you see as "concatenated" is just due to printing `<a[i]<<obj2.getAdultData()`, ie `a[i]` and then `obj2.getAdultData()` without any space between then,  when you want only one of them. I think you can remove `Booking` or make up your mind what it should store: Data of all Children bookings? Data of one children booking? Data of all Chilrden *and*  adult booking?

Comment: Okay, @Jarod42 I will keep in mind about renaming the object as meaningful as I can. See obj2 is used for accessing the names of Adult and Child from the class Booking. I will try this `Booking<std::vector<string>, std::vector<string>> names;` and let you know. Thank you

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Okay, but then why in 1st for loop there is no concatenation i.e names are printed without any space in that. For loop one i.e for a[i] the output for Adult names is right. Only for loop two i.e for Child names the output is like printing two strings without any space in between them. As you said _What you see as "concatenated" is just due to printing <a[i]<<obj2.getAdultData(), ie a[i] and then obj2.getAdultData() without any space between then, when you want only one of them._ Then according to this **Name of Adult 1 : a** and **Name of Adult 2 : b** should be like

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
**Name of Adult 1 : ab**  \n
**Name of Adult 2 : bb**